# Push elements into array without duplicates in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**I'm trying to push elements into an array and decrement the count of it without duplicates in angular.**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash library.

Lodash has a function called unique which removes all duplicates from an array, after that you can then apply the decrementing function...

Like this:

```js
_.uniq([2, 1, 2]);
```

and then the result could be added into your decremental function..

If the duplicates are required, do let me know in the comments section so as to extend the answer..